# Vector as argument of a function

Tags: functions, terminology

Given a function $f(x)=y$ is correct to say that $f\left(\left[\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{array}\right]\right)=\left[\begin{array}{c} y_1 \\ y_2 \\ y_3 \end{array}\right]$?

Comment: Also, it is often more convenient to write $f([x_1,x_2,x_3]^T) = [y_1,y_2,y_3]^T$ in case of long vertical vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, assuming that $x \in A^3$ and $y \in B^3$ for some suitable spaces $A,B$ you just give the explicit representation of those elements which is equivalent to actually writing $x$ or $y$.

If you want to make it even more formal you can say for example that the $x_i$ represent the coordinate entries of $x$, but that is common notation anyways and most people will understand it.

Comment: Unfortunately $x\in R$ and $y\in R$. Sorry, I wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: Do you mean $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^3$? Then the answer remains the same. Otherwise you have to explain how you define $[x_1,x_2,x_3] \in R$